# Xcode IBInspectable Placeholder

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I there any way to specify a placeholder that appears in the Attributes Inspector for an IBInspectable property?

For example, I want:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) IBInspectable NSString *name;
```

to generate an Inspector text field with the placeholder 'enter name'. Currently Xcode displays 'Default' as the text field placeholder.

Comment: Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Not yet as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think so. Might want to [file a Radar](http://bugreport.apple.com). But, in code, you could set a default value of that property in your `-init` method. It’s not perfect, but depending on what you are doing, it might suit your needs.